# Centralize Bottom navigation Click Event Codes

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using Bottom Navigation, For now Bottom navigation click event codes is in MainActivity which work fine for me.

[image]

Now I want to use this bottom navigation in each activity and i wish this bottom navigation click event work for each activity.
Using Include Bottom navigation xml is included in each xml file but click event is not working for me. please help.

Comment: You would be better off working with fragments instead of activities.

Answer (score 1):

To deal with bottomNavigatioView or TabLayout, you have to use the Fragments and it is recommendable to deal with these cases. So, use fragments instead of Activity for each bottomNavigation option. Then your click event works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fragments, This is android recommended Solution.